# The simplification of $(1+a_1\cdot h) \cdot \ldots \cdot (1+a_n\cdot h)$

Tags: analysis, summation, products

I would like to simplify the expression $(1+a_1\cdot h) \cdot \ldots \cdot (1+a_n\cdot h)$. One will later anyway truncate all terms with $h^2$ and greater by considering $h << 1$, but I would like to write down a formula before doing $h<<1$.

So far I have:
\begin{align}
(1+a_1\cdot h) \cdot \ldots \cdot (1+a_n\cdot h) = 1 + h \sum_{j=1}^n a_j + h^2 \sum_{j\ne k}^n a_ja_k + \ldots
\end{align}

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2714401/721644).

Comment: You've got to take care with notation, your term in $h^2$ has to be over $j<k$ or else you double count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denoting with $[n]=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ we obtain
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\prod_{j=1}^n}\color{blue}{\left(1+a_jh\right)}
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\sum_{{S\subseteq [n]}\atop{|S|=k}}\left(\prod_{j\in S}a_j\right)h^k\\
&=\sum_{{S\subseteq [n]}\atop{|S|=0}}\left(\prod_{j\in S}a_j\right)h^0+\sum_{{S\subseteq [n]}\atop{|S|=1}}\left(\prod_{j\in S}a_j\right)h^1+\sum_{k=2}^n\sum_{{S\subseteq [n]}\atop{|S|=k}}\left(\prod_{j\in S}a_j\right)h^k\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=1+\sum_{j=1}^na_jh
+\sum_{k=2}^n\sum_{{S\subseteq [n]}\atop{|S|=k}}\left(\prod_{j\in S}a_j\right)h^k}\\
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$\prod_{i=1}^n\left[1+a_i h \right]=\prod_{i=1}^na_i\left[h + \dfrac{1}{a_i} \right]=\prod_{i=1}^na_i\prod_{i=1}^n\left[h + \dfrac{1}{a_i} \right]$$

The last product can be interpreted as a polynomial in $h$ with degree $n$ in which $-1/a_i$ are the roots of the polynomial. The coefficients can be written down by [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas).